# To whom was Rabi Yehudah Hanasi taken after his brit milah?

Tags: untagged

After his father performed the brit milah on little Rabi Yehudah Hanasi, he was sent to the roman authorities, with the parents, so they can check if it was really done, since there was a decree against it. On the way he was exchanged with a roman baby, the future emperor. I read that they were taken to the roman procurator. But Tosefot mentions "kesar"/king. And if it was to the procurator (who was probably living somewhere in the Middle East), how can he have met the family of the future emperor on the way (wouldnt this family be in Rome)? So was he taken to the procurator or to the emperor?

Comment: Hi Sarah, where did you find the story?

Comment: Tosefot, Avodah Zara 10, 2

Comment: also in the book Stories of the Tzadikim, "The Baby that was Exchanged for Another" and the book Our People page 75

Comment: In case it helps your research, Rebbi was famously swapped with Antoninus, who was later to be the future emperor and Rabbi's close friend.